# Objective-C -> Applescript string (return value) encoding issue

Tags: objective-c, json, encoding, applescript

I am on Objective C, OSX, Xcode 8.3

My app is written in objective-c, but in some places i need some applescript methods to address other applications. From one of these methods i receive a string which is (should) be a JSON. But unfortunately it seems like the inverted commas are wrong - seems like an encoding thing. What can i do in Objective C to transform encoding properly?

In Applescript the text manipulation is very limited. The text is coerced with "as text" and that's it.

```
{„content“:“Test211“,“paragraphStyle“:“1“,“selectedTextFitting“:“0“,“paragraphStyleID“:“120“,“characterStyle“:“1“,“characterStyleID“:“1452“}
```

Encoding drives me crazy... *sigh*

Comment: Is it really encoding or something like automation for quotes like can do TextEdit.app Word.app, etc?

Comment: i will digg into this and let you know

Comment: It's not as limited as you think: `as «class utf8»` coerces the text explicitly to UTF8 and `as Unicode text` coerces the text explicitly to UTF16

Comment: only when you read or write from/to a textfile imho

Comment: It WAS a foormatting issue. pretty hidden though. can be closed.

Comment: Any reason to return JSON from AS? Seems an odd combo. If it's to transfer complex data between AS and ObjC, use AppleScriptObjC, not NSAppleScript. That performs automatic AS↔︎Cocoa record/list/string/number conversions for you. [Quick how-to here.](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html)